# Remove/Disable Style sheet from html page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm using two styles.

For Example **Style1.css** and **Style2.css**.

Style2.css has some styles which overwrite the Style1.css styles.

Is there any way we can remove/disable Styles2.css file from Html while loading?

Comment: try with !important in your style . It will override automattically

Comment: show your code. We will explain better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the stylesheet only after loading:

```
//document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ...
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  var link = document.createElement('link');
  link.rel = "stylesheet";
  link.href = "Styles2.css";
  document.querySelector('head').appendChild( link );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can remove styles dynamically

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  const path = '[pathto]/Styles2.css';
  const styles = document.querySelectorAll('link');
  const style2 = Array.from(styles).find(k => k.href === path);
  const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  head.removeChild(style2);
});
```

you can use @optimus prime answer to add style1

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a problem to use style tags rather than separate files, you can add ids and manipulate them however you want.

HTML:

```
<style id='style1'>color: red;</style>
<style id='style2'>color: red;</style>
```

Javascript:

```
const styleSheet = document.getElementById("#style1");
remove(styleSheet);
```

Answer (score -1):

No you can't just remove or disable stylesheet but one thing you can you can override style the style you want to add just make as !important other file style should be simple.
Or you can change position of file 
Like more important the second file 
Like 


 I need V2 style sheet so i will add later for the first all style should b render with second file